# Opening a text file using HTML only

Tags: html

I have been assigned a project where I must select and display a txt file only using HTML AND CSS. I have already learned how to use JavaScript, JQuery, and PHP do to this but this project requires HTML and CSS only. So far I have mainly tried using the  to select my file and that seems to work fine but I can't figure out how to obtain the value of the file without using js,JQuery, or PHP, and to display the txt file I have tried using the  which seems like the only way to display a txt file with only HTML, but I do not know. Any advice would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: I don't even think that's possible...

Comment: Only full html solution is an iframe

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a programming language.

Comment: HTML is a markup language where you can create structure and if you want to style the structure or want to look beautiful structure use `CSS` (Cascading Style Sheets) and if you want to process HTML elements/controls or other things like `.txt` files or other document files like `.doc` or `.csv` definitely you need programming language. There is no functionality/feature in HTML to process `.txt`, `.doc` or `.csv` files.

Answer (score 2):

HTML and CSS provide no mechanism to achieve this.

The closest you could come would be to link to the text file or show it in an iframe, but there is no way to dynamically determine which file to link to with HTML/CSS alone.

If you want to process user input then you need a *programming* language.